# ¿Es posible recibir notificaciones de Firebase en Android con la app cerrada?

Tags: java, android, firebase, servicio

El código ya lo tengo funcionando pero solo me recibe la notificación si la app esta abierta o en segundo plano, no si esta cerrada.
Estoy buscando mucho pero no encuentro la solución.

Nose si dependerá de algo del Manifest:

```
   <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessagingServ">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDServ">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

El archivo FirebaseMessagingServ es el encargado de sacar la notificación:

```
       public class FirebaseMessagingServ extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
               String from = message.getFrom();
               Map data = message.getData();

               showNotification(message.getData().get("message"));
            }

            private void showNotification(String sms){
                  Intent i = new Intent(this, Main_Principal.class);
                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                  .setAutoCancel(true)
                  .setContentTitle("FCM test")
                  .setContentText(sms)
                  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_app_grande)
                  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                  NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                  manager.notify(0,builder.build());
             }
       }
```

El cual funciona perfectamente siempre que la app este abierta o en segundo plano, no funciona cuando esta cerrada.

La clase FirebaseInstanceIDServ solo se encarga de extraer el Token y enviármelo a la Sql.

Mi problema por los comentarios está en el System tray, por si tuviera algo que ver este es mi php encargado del envío:

```
 <?php
    //Conectamos BD
    include("conn.php");
    $con = conectar();

    function send_notification ($tokens,$message, $notification){
    $url = 'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $tokens,
        'data' => $message,
        'notification' => $notification);

     $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AIzaSyB_317WEFmazhxxxxxxxxxma3o81qjA',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
      $result = curl_exec($ch);           
      if ($result === FALSE) {
          die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
      }
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
   }

   $sql = "SELECT token From fcm_tokens";

   $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
   $tokens = Array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
             $tokens[] = $row["token"];
        }
    }

    mysql_close($con);

    $message = array("message" => "Prueba de FCM");
    $notification = array("message" => "Prueba de FCMd", "body" => "cuerpooo", "icon" => "ic_launcher");
    $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message,$notification);
    echo $message_status;

   ?>
```

Cuando la app esta activa llega la información del 'Data' y cuando esta en background llega la información del 'notification', pero cuando la app esta cerrada (proceso matado) no llega ningún tipo de notificación.

¿Debería hacer algún cambio?

---

Noticia de última hora:
Las pruebas las esto haciendo en mi móvil Xiaomi, lo acabo de probar en Nexus 5 y ahí si que llegan aunque la app este cerrada, eso sí solo desde la consola no des de PHP. ¿Alguien sabe la explicación?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si, podrias crear services de android los cuales permiten ejecutar procesos en segundo plano y/o recibir notificaciones https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html El coding es algo extenso para poder escribirlo aquí, pero te dejo el enlace de un gist que realiza algo parecido https://gist.github.com/vikrum/6170193

Comment: Según la documentación, si la aplicación no esta corriendo la notificación va directo al System Tray, o sea entra sin pasar por tu app. Pero cuando el usuario toca la notificación se abre la aplicación y se pasa la data como extras en el intent. Te dejo los links a la documentación de Firebase: - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages ---
En caso que no te este saltando la notificación (aunque no pase por tu código) actualiza la pregunta y trata de poner algo de código como para

Comment: Me parece que lo tengo según la documentación y funcioar funciona a menos que la aplicación tenga el proceso muerto...

Comment: Aunque mates el proceso debería funcionar igual. Intenta enviarte notificaciones desde la consola de firebase así sacas del medio el posible error de backend.

Comment: Otra cosa para probar es agregarle datos extras a la notificación, no sólo el contenido. Mandarle también un título y algún campo más como para probar. Creo que si tienen extra Info las trata diferentes.

Comment: Tienes razón dependiendo si envias 'Data' o 'notification' recoge un valo o otro dependiendo si la pp esta en foreground  o background. Tando des de consola como des de php funciona a no ser que el proceo de la app este killer, que obtengo el mismo resultado en los dos casos no llega nada.
Llevo ya dos días con esto y no paro de probar cosas es bastante desesperante.

Comment: Es lo próximo que voy a probar, pero estoy confuso ya que todo el mundo dice que devería funcionar así como lo tengo, y en ningún manual he visto que creen un Service aparte para controlar que este el Firebase siempre activo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado!**
 Al final eran por permisos del Xiaomi... al parecer si no reclamo permisos de arrancar al inicio de sistema no permitía mostrar notificaciones con la app cerrada.

Recomiendo este hilo a todos los que quieran implementar FCM ya que esta muy completo.

Y gracias a todos ya que no hubiera sido posible sin vosotros.

Gracias!

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta Victor, no especificas que permiso al arrancar el sistema.Porque no agregas esa información.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia esto en el archivo .PHP y listo!!!

```
$mensaje = array("body"=>"tu mensaje", "title"=>"Titulo");
$fields = array(
'to' => "sPODNKLSsdfsd:ASFALSDKFJLA....",
'notification' => $mensaje),
);
```

**Necesito ayuda también**
Ya puedes recibir la notificación con la app en primer plano? me refiero cuando recibes una notificación la puedes mostrarla con un Toast o algo en un Activity...

Comment: Si la puedes pasar a una activity si, enlaza el dato como string dentro del toast.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es que cuando se reciba la notificación o mensaje se muestre automáticamente, tipo WatsApp, cuando recibe un mensaje se muestre automáticamente, se podrá con Firebase?

Comment: Tu no lo has integrado? Como has podido resolver mi duda? Aún no lo he probado ya comentaré los resultados.

Comment: @Y.Vasquez necesitas crear un servicio dentro de tu aplicación Android, de manera que este ejecutándose en segundo plano sin necesidad de que el usuario este en contacto con la interfaz, asi podras tener una conexion.

http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/

Comment: @VictorMaldonado ya lo tengo funcionando al recibir la notificación, ya sea en segundo plano o que la app ya esté cerrada, ya lo tengo funcionando desde la consola y desde mi servidor (archivo .php)

Pero en tu clase FirebaseMessagingServ pega lo que tiene este link: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

Comment: Me podrías pasar el Php? Algo no me acaba de encajar

Comment: Aca te dejo la funcion en .php

Answer (score 0):

Este sería la función en PHP

```
function eniarNotificacion($mssg, $title) {
$message = array("body"=>$mssg, "title"=>"Titulo");
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array(
      'to' => "gPdofldkfgj:ADSDgslñkdgdsf...",
      'notification' => $message,
  );
  $headers = array(
      'Content-Type:application/json',
      'Authorization:key=ASfasdflsdkjlaksLKAJDALSKdfassd...'
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);             
  if ($result === FALSE) {
      die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: IMPRESIONANTE: Me he dado cuenta que tanto con mi código como con el tuyo, en mi terminal Xiaomi no me llegan las notificaciones si la app esta cerrada (whatsapp, intagram,etc, si llegan) y en un Nexus si llegan las notificaciones. Alguien podría saber el motivo? Abro otro post?

Comment: Amm no se cual sería la razón, yo ya lo he probado en un galaxy S5 y en un S4, me funciona en las dos, e incluso si no tengo el telefono conectado a internet se envían y se notifica cuando me conecto... yo descargue el ejemplo nativo de Google en GitHub y copie las clases a mi proyecto y listo !!!